# Prove that the sequence of functions $f_n$ is equicontinuos, but with not uniformly convergent subsequence in $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, equicontinuity

**Question**: Prove that the sequence of functions $f_n:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ below is equicontinuous and simply converges to $f\equiv\dfrac{1}{2}$, but with not uniformly convergent subsequence in $(0,1)$.
$$f_n=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{4}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+\dfrac{1}{2}&,x\in\left(0,\dfrac{1}{2\pi n}\right]\\[1em]
\quad\quad\quad\dfrac{1}{2}&,x\in\left[\dfrac{1}{2\pi n},1\right)
\end{cases}.$$

**My attempt**: For the pointwise convergence, we have:

• $x=\dfrac{1}{2\pi n}$
$$f_n\left(\dfrac{1}{2\pi n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin(2\pi n)+\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}.$$

• $x>\dfrac{1}{2\pi n}$
$$f_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}.$$

So, I think that we can conclude that $f_n\to f=\dfrac{1}{2}$ simply.

Now, my problem is to prove that the sequence of functions is equicontinuous with not uniformly convergent subsequence... what I was trying to do is to prove by the definition of equicontinuity:

> A sequence of functions is equicontinuous in $x_0\in X$ when the set of functions $F=\{f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n,\dots\}$ is equicontinuos at $x_0$, in other words, for all $\varepsilon>0$, exists $\delta>0$ such that
> $$x\in X,|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\varepsilon,\forall~n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

and trying to find a $\delta$:

$$\left|\left[\dfrac{1}{4}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+\dfrac{1}{2}\right]-\left[\dfrac{1}{4}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right)+\dfrac{1}{2}\right]\right|=\left|\dfrac{1}{4}\left[\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right)\right]\right|$$

but it didn't work. I don't know if I'm on the right way... and I also need to prove that the sequence of functions doesn't have a uniformly convergent subsequence in $(0,1)$.

**Edit**: I think I prove that $f_n$ is equicontinuous using the mean value theorem:
$$\left|\dfrac{1}{4}\left[\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right)\right]\right|\overset{\mbox{MVT}}{=}\dfrac{1}{4}\left|\dfrac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)}{c}\cdot(x-x_0)\right|\leq\left|-\dfrac{1}{c}\right||x-x_0|<\dfrac{1}{c}\delta.$$

Now, choosing $\delta=c\cdot\varepsilon$ we have that $f_n$ is equicontinuous... but I still don't know how to prove that the sequence of functions doesn't have a uniformly convergent subsequence in $(0,1)$...

Comment: $|f_n(x)-1/2| \ge 1/8$ for lots of $x$ arbitrary close to zero, so if $f_n$ or (a subsequence) would be uniformly convergent there will be $n_0$ st $|f_n(x)-1/2| <1/12, n \ge n_0$ and all $x \in (0,1)$ which contradicts the above with an $0<x < \dfrac{1}{2\pi (n_0+1)}, \sin 1/x=1$

Comment: I didn't understand the numbers you chose... why $1/8$ and $1/12$? And this is a way to proof that $f_n$ doesn't have a uniformly convergent subsequence in $(0,1)$? I didn't get the contratition... sorry for my slow thinking

Comment: the point is that $|f_n(x)-1/2|$ oscillates like $1/4 \sin 1/x$ for small $x$ so it is at least $1/8$ quite a lot of time when $\sin 1/x$ is at least $1/2$; uniform convergence means that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $n(\epsilon), |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all  $n,m \ge n(\epsilon), x \in (0,1)$ and letting $m \to \infty$ this means $|f_n(x)-1/2| \le \epsilon$ for all $n \ge n(\epsilon), x \in (0,1)$; but choosing $\epsilon =1/12, n=n(\epsilon)+1$ and $x$ appropriate so $\sin 1/x =1$ and $x$ small enough so $f_n(x)=1/4 \sin (1/x)+1/2=1/4+1/2$ we get the contradiction $1/4 < 1/12$